# RSpec: assert that mocks are correct

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, testing, rspec

When writing RSpec tests, I often find myself mocking various functions in the code base. However, there doesn't seem to be anything in place to prevent me from accidentally mocking the functions incorrectly, and I would like to enforce this *somehow*.

For a concrete example, let's say I have the function I'm testing:

```
def function_under_test
  some_function(a: 1, b: 2, c: 3)
end

def some_function(a:, b:, c:)
  { a: a, b: [b, b, b], c: { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 } }
end
```

And a test for it

```
it 'should return the correct result' do
  subject = function_under_test
  expect(some_function).to_return(1)
  expect(subject).to eq(1)
end
```

I completely changed the interface of the function, but my test still passed. I love how straightforward it is to write mocks, but it would be really great to be able to enforce that the mocks I'm writing are following the interface provided by the function. Is there any way to accomplish this? I'm ok with including examples, or shared contexts, or what not, as long it accomplishes what I need.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are not testing `some_function`, your tests is useless. Don't use mocks until  tests become slow and very very very complicated to setup.

Comment: Those are not mocks, `subject` is already used by RSpec and should be used as a block, e.g. `subject { some_function(...) }`. `.to_return` doesn't exist, it's just `.to eq`

Comment: Re: Fabio - this is just a contrived example. In the application I am actually working in, there are a number of interconnected services, and I want to mock their client library functions in a way that asserts that the mock I (or others) have written are correct.

Comment: Re: Dorian - I've updated the example to perhaps make a little more sense. I have a function under test, which is calling some_function, and I wish to mock it because its expensive, but I want to assert that the mock result is in the correct format.

Comment: Your example still doesn't make much sense, calling `some_function` without parameters (in the test) would raise `ArgumentError (missing keywords: a, b, c)`

Comment: Re: Dorian - I'm not calling "some_function" without parameters in test - I'm setting up an expectation that it returns the value 1. The function under test is the one calling some_function.

Answer (score 0):

Named parameters are forced to have a value, calling `some_function` without parameters would cause an exception.

So ruby is already making sure you pass values for the `a`, `b`, and `c` parameters (except if you define default values)

Comment: That's great, but how do I assert on the format of the result?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean the type of the return value, you could do `expect(some_function(...)).to be_an(Hash)` for instance